# Unveil load all images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to use Unveil JQuery plugin, but don´t work. This plugin is similar to Lazyload but more *simple*, without effects and events.

When I load a HTML, plugin load all images and I need load one by one when I scroll. [Chrome load all images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbg4U.jpg).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <style>
    img {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
    } 
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/4/" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/3/" >
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/2" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/1" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/6" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/7" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/8" />
    <img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unveil/1.3.0/jquery.unveil.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $("img").unveil(0, function(){

        $(this).load(function(){
            this.style.opacity=1;

        });
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Any idea?

Comment: `but don´t work` - if it did, you wouldn't be asking a question ... can you elaborate, what does the code do? how does that differ from what you expect it to do?

Comment: With this JQuery images ONLY load when I scroll, but in my case when I open HTML load all images. See this example http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This effect need image size to works propertly. For example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Prueba</title>
<style>
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  width:10%; 
  height:10%;
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/4/" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/3/" >
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/2" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/1" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/6" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/7" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/8" />
<img src="loader.gif" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/9" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-    2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unveil/1.3.0/jquery.unveil.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("img").unveil(0, function(){

    $(this).load(function(){
        this.style.opacity=1;

    });
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```